# How can I adjust height of ever row of a grid in BindableLayout to fit the content's height?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a cross platform app on both iOS and Android.
Now I want to display some searched result in a big grid, every cell can be clicked. There should be 3 results in every row, and every cell in a same row should has a same height with a shadow frame. Every result may have a different height.

Here is a image demonstrated what I want (just like Excel):
[image: Just like excel]

Firstly, I tried to use a BindableLayout Grid, which has an indexed item list. Every item has a Row and a Col property to fill into a cell. But the Grid's height is different.
Here is the xaml.

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <mvvm:GridViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="5,50,5,0" >
        <Label Text="Result:" />
        <ScrollView x:Name="scrollViewResult" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Grid BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding GridResult}" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*" RowDefinitions="Auto" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Every cell is a nested Grid. Using grid is for the purpose of button.-->
                        <Grid x:Name="NestedGrid" Grid.Row="{Binding Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Col}" RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" >
                            <!-- Frame for the corner radius and shadow.-->
                            <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" Margin="1">
                                <!-- Label text is real display text.-->
                                <Label Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="-15" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <!-- Here placing a hole-cell button for a better click gesture. -->
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

It likes below. emmmmm, not good (a BindableLayout Grid):
[image: A BindableLayout Grid]

Then, I tried to use nested BindableLayout Grid(only one row) in a BindableLayout StackLayout. Every item in StackLayout is a list, every item in the list has a Col property to fill into a cell. Act a little better but not enough, for some short text will still hold large blank, and some has different height in a row.

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <mvvm:GridInGridViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="5,50,5,0" >
        <Label Text="Result:" />
        <ScrollView x:Name="scrollViewResult" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding GridResult}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Every Grid has one row and 3 columns.-->
                        <Grid x:Name="ARowGrid" Margin="5,5,5,0" ColumnSpacing="5" RowSpacing="15" RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="30*,30*,30*" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!-- Every cell in ARowGrid is a nested Grid. Using grid is for the purpose of button.-->
                                    <Grid x:Name="NestedGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="{Binding Col}" RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" >
                                        <!-- Frame for the corner radius and shadow.-->
                                        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0">
                                            <!-- Label text is real display text.-->
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="-15" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Frame>
                                        <!-- Here placing a hole-cell button for a better click gesture. -->
                                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Margin="5"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

It acts like this (a BindableLayout Grid in BindableLayout StackLayout):
[image: A BindableLayout Grid in BindableLayout StackLayout]

So is there any way to adjust height of ever row of a grid to fit the content's height, with every cell in a row has the same height, the height is the max height of content(may be add some margin).

Added 1.======================

I tried the collection view. It not works well too.
The Xamarin as follows.

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <mvvm:GridViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="5,50,5,0" >
        <Label Text="Result:" />
        <ScrollView x:Name="scrollViewResult" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding GridResult}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                     Span="3"
                                     VerticalItemSpacing="5"
                                     HorizontalItemSpacing="5" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Every cell is a nested Grid. Using grid is for the purpose of button.-->
                        <Grid x:Name="NestedGrid" RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" VerticalOptions="Start">
                            <!-- Frame for the corner radius and shadow.-->
                            <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" Margin="1">
                                <!-- Label text is real display text.-->
                                <Label Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="-15" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <!-- Here placing a hole-cell button for a better click gesture. -->
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is the result. Emm, not well.
[CollectionView result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZfDi.jpg)

Comment: Try collection view with vertical grid layout - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid. Not sure if rows will have different heights, but worth trying. If use grid in each item, set row height to "Auto".

Comment: Thanks. But the CollectionView with vertical grid span=3 is not working well.  Every cell whose text less than or equal 2 rows has the same height, and other cells has their own. And The same row wont get a same height.

Comment: How about put `label` inside a `StackLayout`?

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: @Shaw This is a way. Put another label named HiddenLabel in every cell. HiddenLabel equals to the longest label's text in every row.  Add another frame with this HiddenLabel in every cell and set the backgroudcolor Transparent. Dont know if there is any performance issues. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT I've uploaded a project for test.  [link](https://github.com/guyhuang/AdjustHeightForEveryRow) Is there any other method to solve it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test on myside and I found out that the RowDefinitions of inside grid is auto, if you set it as "*", the cells will have the same heigt.As microsoft document says about grid length:

The GridLength struct specifies a row height or a column width in terms of the GridUnitType enumeration, which has three members:

> Auto – the row height or column width is autosized based on the cell
> contents (Auto in XAML).

> Star – leftover row height or column width is
> allocated proportionally (a number followed by * in XAML).

> Absolute – the row height or column width is a value in device-independent units (a number in XAML).

Comment: That's the correct answer. I set the Grid RowDefinitions = "*", it works. Thanks. (However I am too new to raise the answer.)

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

As what i mentioned above, adding a hidden label in a hidden frame can solve this problem. Also I set the Button's HeightRequest to a small value(just 1 row) and set Margin to a fixed value(just 5).

Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:RecForYou.Mvvm"
             x:Class="RecForYou.GridInGridPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <mvvm:GridInGridViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="5,50,5,0" >
            <Label Text="Result:" />
            <ScrollView x:Name="scrollViewResult" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding GridResult}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- Every Grid has one row and 3 columns.-->
                            <Grid x:Name="ARowGrid" Margin="5,5,5,0" ColumnSpacing="5" RowSpacing="15" RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="30*,30*,30*" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <!-- Every cell in ARowGrid is a nested Grid. Using grid is for the purpose of button.-->
                                        <Grid x:Name="NestedGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="{Binding Col}" RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" >
                                            <!-- Frame for the corner radius and shadow.-->
                                            <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0">
                                                <!-- Label text is real display text.-->
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="-15" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Frame>
                                            <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                                <!-- Label text is real display text.-->
                                                <Label Text="{Binding HiddenValue}" Margin="-15" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Transparent"/>
                                            </Frame>
                                            <!-- Here placing a hole-cell button for a better click gesture. -->
                                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Margin="5" HeightRequest="10"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And the hole project is in [github](https://github.com/guyhuang/AdjustHeightForEveryRow)
Here is the result.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKvTJ.jpg)

I don't know if there is any performance issues for another frame and another label.
Is there any better solution?